# Create dynamic variable assignment inside $.post - JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

Could i use dynamic variable inside my `$.post` JQuery/Ajax code? I would like to know where i am making mistakes or i am misunderstood the useage of `$.post` of JQuery.

I have **dynamically created variables** and value assigned to it from **`text-fields`**. Now i want to use those variables inside `$.post` of JQuery.

**Code Below:**

The part that's working fine:

```js
var boxFields = ["customerId","customerName","customerContact","customerEmail"];
var boxVar = [];

for(var x=0;x<4;x++)
{
 boxVar[x] = $("#" + boxFields[x]).val();
}

alert(boxVar[1]); //Just random call to check it works.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="customerId" value="12345"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="customerName" value="John Doe"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="customerContact" value="XXXXXXXXXX"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="customerEmail" value="xxxxxx@xxx.com"/>
```

Now i have dynamically generated variables *`(check above hidden snippet for that)`*. So to use those in `$.post`.

### **Update:**

Sorry, for missing the actual part

**My Problem/Question**: Could i use for loop to create dynamic objects inside `$.post`.

**Whole Code:**

```js
var boxFields = ["customerId","customerName","customerContact","customerEmail"];
var boxVar = [];

for(var x=0;x<4;x++)
{
 boxVar[x] = $("#" + boxFields[x]).val();
}

$.post("url.php",
{
  requestType: "updateRow",
  
  for(var y=0;y<4;y++)
  {
    boxFields[y]: boxVar[y] 
    if(y!=3){,}  
  }
  
  /* I want above code to work like this:
  requestType: "updateRow",
  customerId: 12345,
  customerName: John Doe,
  customerContact: XXXXXXXXXX,
  customerEmail: xxxxxx@xxx.com
  */
},
function(data)
{
 //Success Code Lines..........
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="customerId" value="12345"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="customerName" value="John Doe"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="customerContact" value="XXXXXXXXXX"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="customerEmail" value="xxxxxx@xxx.com"/>
```

> **Also would like to know how to prevent from getting SQL Injection**

Thank You!

Comment: What's your question?  What isn't working?  All you've said is that your code "is working fine".  So... What are you asking?  As for the SQL injection, you'd handle that wherever you actually interact with a SQL server.  Which you're not doing anywhere in this code.

Comment: **Sorry for missing the actual Question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could i use for loop to create dynamic objects inside $.post.

Not *inside* the call to `.post()`, no.  Which has nothing to do with `.post()` itself or with AJAX or anything like that, but simply as the syntax of the language.  Consider your attempt:

```
$.post("url.php",
{
  requestType: "updateRow", 
  for(var y=0;y<4;y++)
  {
    boxFields[y]: boxVar[y] 
    if(y!=3){,}  
  }
  //...
```

The second argument to the function is simply an object.  And things like loops and other control structures aren't valid for *declaring an object*.  What you *can* do is, well, what you already did before.  Build the object, then use it in the function call:

```
var someArray = [];
for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++)
{
    someArray[x] = someValue;
}
// etc.

// later...
$.post('url.php', someArray, function () { /.../ });
```

Basically, a *loop* is not an object that can be passed to a function.  It's a control structure for imperative code.

Comment: So basically i cant create dynamic objects *`(like: customerName: )`* from array? I have to go with the previous way i did?

Comment: @divy3993: What's wrong with creating the object before using it?  What actual problem are you trying to solve here?  You can create things dynamically, but you have to do so within the syntax of the language.

Comment: What i am trying to do here is that, Taking the values of array from `boxFields` which i can use to grab value of `text-fields` as they have `similar id's` and also use those inside `$.post` as object name  *`(like: customerName: )`*, etc.

Comment: Whole point is just to make code Shorter. Thank You by the way for your response.

Comment: @divy3993: "Shorter" code is not necessarily "better" code.  Don't try to make your code as clever as possible.  Just make it simple and clear.  Build the object, use the object in the function call.  If you can clearly and easily build the object in a single statement of code, then you can do that in the function call directly.  But you can't use entire control structures in the way that you're attempting.

Comment: Ok. Thanks and i am not the one downvoting your answer. Instead count me for an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put a loop inside your post function (a loop is not an object), but you can construct your data before the post. The cleaner way to go is this one:

```
var data = {
  requestType: "updateRow"
};

$('input').each(function() { // change the selector to be more precise
  data[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(data);

$.post("url.php", data, function(data) {
  //Success Code Lines..........
});
```

**SQL injection**

Even if you can do some checking in JS, the only way to really prevent SQL injection is to escape/check/use special methods **on the server side**, when it interacts with an SQL database.

Comment: That must happen as it can not find here in this case file named `url.php`.

Comment: Of course that is the problem. But since the data are correct, it should work properly for you.

Comment: **Sorry for missing the actual Question.**